# SQL query on Many to Many with intersection

Tags: sql, django, django-mptt

I am working with [django-categories](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories/tree/master/categories) which uses [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/docs/forms.rst) under the hood. (That implicates db structure that I am using.)

I have some products:

```
product       
--------      
id | name     
1  | Apple    
2  | Orange   
3  | Tomato
```

Categories:

```
categories
----------
id | name       | parent | tree_id | level
1  | Type       | null   | 1       | 1
2  | Fruit      | 1      | 1       | 2
3  | Vegetable  | 1      | 1       | 2
4  | Color      | null   | 2       | 1
5  | Orange     | 4      | 2       | 2
6  | Red        | 4      | 2       | 2
7  | Green      | 4      | 2       | 2
8  | Dark green | 7      | 2       | 3
9  | Orange     | 4      | 2       | 2
```

Which is tree with single root (nodes have also fields `order`, `left`, `right` but I don't think that it is relevant here):

```
root/
├── Type/
│   ├── Fruit
│   ├── Vegetable
└── Color/
    ├── Red
    ├── Green
    |   └── Dark green
    └── Orange
```

And M2M table:

```
product_categories
------------------
id | product_id | category_id
1  | 1          | 2
2  | 1          | 6
3  | 2          | 2
4  | 2          | 9
5  | 3          | 3
6  | 3          | 5
```

So I am having all categories in one tree, but I can group them by `tree_id`.
Now I would like to find products that are `Fruits` and are `Red` OR `Orange` (so to get Apple an Orange)

I was expecting that query to give me what I want:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
"product"."id", "product"."name" 
FROM
"product" 
INNER JOIN "product_categories" ON ("product"."id" = "product_categories"."product_id") 
WHERE 
("product_categories"."category_id" IN ('2') 
AND "product_categories"."category_id" IN ('6', '9'))
```

but I am getting no results.

It could be achieved by querying multiple times, once per tree, and then looking for intersection, but I believe it is doable by single query.

Comment: Attach sample output please. This is definitely wrong: `product_categoryes IN ('2') AND ... IN ('6','9')`. The value can't be 2 and 6 or 2 and 9 at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
"product"."id", "product"."name" 
FROM
"product" 
INNER JOIN "product_categories" ON ("product"."id" = "product_categories"."product_id") 
WHERE 
("product_categories"."category_id" IN ('6', '9'))
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT 
"product"."id", "product"."name" 
FROM
"product" 
INNER JOIN "product_categories" ON ("product"."id" = "product_categories"."product_id") 
WHERE 
("product_categories"."category_id" IN ('2'))
```